# net/http response encoding issues on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ruby

Identical requests and headers to same server from two different platforms get as response two diferent encodings:

From Win7 PC I get UTF-8 which is what I want.

From Raspberry pi I get ASCII-8bit. After encoding response to UTF-8 it becomes corrupted.

```
resp['Content-Type'] = application/json
```

Ruby version on both devices and raspbian version:

```
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [armv7l-linux-eabihf]
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

Linux raspberrypi 4.9.41-v7+ #1023 SMP Tue Aug 8 16:00:15 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Setup Considerations:

```
Connecting via SHH PuttY
Connections made from raspberry pass through an external proxy.
```

Why is data not UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

This may be worth checking :

Go to your Raspberry Pi config window, and under localization, click Locale and see if your character set is set to UTF-8

Comment: Yes. My locale is UTF-8